# Need array in json with php json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have a array as this one :

```
$priceArray = [
            'pricing' => [
                'Prices' => [
                   'quantity' => 1,
                   'price' => floatval($price)
                ]
           ]
        ];
```

After json_encode it gives me :

```
{"pricing":
     {"Prices":
        {"quantity":1,
          "price":24
        }
    }
}
```

But i need :

```
{
    "pricing":
       {"Prices":[
           {"quantity":1,
              "price":24
           }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can i become that the Prices element is a array instead of a object ?

Comment: What you say you need is not valid JSON

Comment: But a api needs it this way ?

Comment: I highly doubt that.  You should double-check the exact format.

Comment: Maybe api needs array of objects -  `[{}, {}]`?

Comment: **If** an API requires that format (and I agree with @PatrickQ that it would be very unusual), then it's not a JSON API, and you won't be able to use `json_encode` to talk to it.

Comment: Sorry guys it was my mistake ! , i corrected the code it needs indeed a array of objects.

Comment: So then your original array needs to have an array of arrays for Prices

Comment: Thanks didn't know it works that way !

Comment: @RudiWerner  Do consider accepting an answer so that people know that you question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `Prices` element of your array is a single key-indexed array.  To produce your desired result, it needs to be an array of key-indexed arrays.

```
$priceArray = [
        'pricing' => [
            'Prices' => [
               [
                   'quantity' => 1,
                   'price' => floatval($price)
               ]
            ]
       ]
    ];
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec17f6ef870ee1c15098f965ddbdbe901fa35877)

Answer (score 0):

```
$priceArray = [
    'pricing' => [
        'Prices' => [[
           'quantity' => 1,
           'price' => floatval($price)
        ]]
   ]
];
```

This will produce

```
{
    "pricing": {
        "Prices": [{
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 4
        }]
    }
}
```

You simply need to wrap your `Prices` data in another array.